# daterangepicker isInvalidDate() is not properly working

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

I'm using the daterangepicker from this website (http://www.daterangepicker.com/).
I want to have some dates that can't be selected and I try to that with the method isInvalidDate().

This is the code I use:

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  },
    isInvalidDate: function(date) {
            var dateRanges = [
                    { 'start': moment('2019-01-10'), 'end': moment('2019-01-15') }
            ];
            return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                    return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
            }, false);
    });
});
```

When I try to add the isInvalidDate() method, the daterangepicker is not working anymore. Does someone know what I do wrong?

Comment: You have invalid syntax.  The `isInvalidDate` key should belong to the same object as the `opens` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left',
            isInvalidDate: function(date) {
                    var dateRanges = [
                            { 'start': moment('2019-01-10'), 'end': moment('2019-01-15') }
                    ];
                    return dateRanges.reduce(function(bool, range) {
                            return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
                    }, false);
        }
    });
    });
```